# iPhone sdk: how to separate the NSString

Tags: iphone, sdk, nsstring

I am working on the google calendar, for this I have add one more feature like Quick add event to google calendar from my app.

I have to separate one string into sub string like this (which come from UITextView)

**on 24-03-2011 9.30AM I have to meet my boss.**

here I have to **separate** Date(24-03-2011), Time (9.30AM) and String (I have to meet by boss.)

and I have to store in different NSStrings.

Please suggest me, how to work out with this.

Thank you.

Comment: Is the date portion of that string always going to be the exact same format?

Comment: @kubi no, it wont be same string changes as per user usage

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSRegularExpression` for this.